# difference between sql server fulltext search service and SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-services, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

Please let me know the difference between these two windows services

sql server fulltext search service and SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The filter daemon launcher service is there solely to launch instances of the search filter daemons, they are launched by separate processes for security reasons.

The following diagram explains the architecture in more detail:

[Full Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017#architecture)